# I can't play any sound with 'exec' node from node-red

Tags: node-red

There is no way I can play any sound with the 'exec' node from node-red, although through the raspberry pi command line it works with the same command:

```
 aplay -D default /home/pi/.node-red/public/Cuckoo-sound-effect.wav
```

Even the node-red output is the same:

> Playing WAVE '/home/pi/.node-red/public/Cuckoo-sound-effect.wav' : Signed 16 bit Little Endian, Rate 44100 Hz, Stereo

This is the implemented flow:

```
[{"id":"ef757da2.68916","type":"exec","z":"83beb11f.6c8ed","command":"aplay","addpay":true,"append":"-D default","useSpawn":"","timer":"","oldrc":false,"name":"aplay","x":290,"y":2520,"wires":[["bfe7b588.f58108"],["2632e1b.090841e"],[]]},{"id":"bfe7b588.f58108","type":"debug","z":"83beb11f.6c8ed","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":510,"y":2480,"wires":[]},{"id":"d3481977.0432e8","type":"inject","z":"83beb11f.6c8ed","name":"","topic":"","payload":"/home/pi/.node-red/public/Cuckoo-sound-effect.wav","payloadType":"str","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":"","x":110,"y":2520,"wires":[["ef757da2.68916"]]},{"id":"2632e1b.090841e","type":"debug","z":"83beb11f.6c8ed","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"payload","x":510,"y":2520,"wires":[]}]
```

Can anyone please indicate what I am doing wrong ?? Thanks a lot !!

Comment: That is odd, but something must be different... only thing I can think of is the order of the args? maybe? I believe the `exec` node will append the payload before the extra args. Does the command line `aplay <filename> -D default` work? The docs I see show the args before the filename (but it really should not matter). Also, are you running the command under the same pi user as node-red is running? You could try using the full path to the `aplay` executable...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replay. Yes, the command line "aplay <filename> -D default" actually works. Node-red is running under the same unser as the pi (although for node-red I have created a different unser-name). Is that the problem you think? Thanks again!

Comment: Have you tried using the full path to the executable `aplay` command? What does `ls -l </full/path/to/aplay>` return? (after substituting the actual path)

Comment: The full path to `aplay` (`</usr/bin/aplay>` in my case) also doesn't work. The `ls -l` command in this path returns the following result for aplay (among many others commands...):  `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      58864 Jan 23  2017 aplay`

Comment: Ok, the permissions on the aplay program look good -- everyone is able to read and execute the file. Just make sure you **do not** put the angle brackets around the path in your exec node properties...

Comment: Sure! The angle brackets are not part of the command :)

Answer (score 0):

In 2021 Node-Red 2.x has nodes to play (mp3 + wav) audio files both locally and on the dashboard.
So maybe exec is not needed any more.

[image]